# Multi Dynamic Routes (react-router-dom)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

i have two different dynamic routes, why second dynamic route doesn't work (its return Activities component it should be Hotspots ) thanks in advance

```
 <Switch>
        <Route exact path ='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path={`/:City/:CatName`} component={Activities} />
        <Route  path={`/:City/Hotspots`} component={Hotspots} />
      </Switch>
```

here is Links

```
<li>
                    <span><Link to={`/${Order.City.replace(' ', '-')}/Hotspots`}>Hotspots</Link></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span><Link to={`/${Order.City.replace(' ', '-')}/Activities`}>Activities</Link></span>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because url `City/Hotspots` is getting in `Activities` route.

As you are setting Activities route with `:CatName` it indicates that this part
of the URL is a placeholder, so when your URL are like `/:City/Hotspots` its understand the Hotspots is as placeholder for `:CatName`.

To fix it just change the route's order, leaving `Hotspots` route as first, like:

```
<Route path={`/:City/Hotspots`} component={Hotspots} />
<Route path={`/:City/:CatName`} component={Activities} />
```

So, now when you entered `/:City/Hotspots`, the first route that react-router-dom find will be the right one, and any other path with `/:City/` will go to `Activities` route.